# Need help understanding MySql syntax

Tags: mysql, sql, union, mysql-error-1064

I am stuck on this hackerrank problem for MySql and keep receiving a syntax error. I am trying to select the cities with the shortest and longest names that comes alphabetically.

When I try with order by city limit 1 on both of them I receive an error. When I only order by city limit 1 after the second query I only receive a response from the first query.

```
(select CITY, length(CITY) from STATION order by length(CITY) limit 5) order by city limit 1; 
UNION 
(select CITY, length(CITY) from STATION order by length(CITY) DESC limit 5) order by city limit 1;
```

This is the error I receive

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UNION 
(select CITY, length(CITY) from STATION order by length(CITY) DESC limit ' at line 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 4 `order by`s where only two are necessary.

```
(select CITY, length(CITY)
 from STATION
 order by length(CITY)
 limit 1
) union all
(select CITY, length(CITY)
 from STATION
 order by length(CITY) DESC
 limit 1
);
```

It is unclear why you would want `limit 5` in the subquery, but then `limit 1` outside it.

Another problem with your query is that you have a semicolon after the first subquery, in effect splitting the compound query into two -- and `union` is not a valid keyword for starting a query.

Answer (score 1):

By terminating your first `SELECT` query with `;` you have made it a completely separate statement.

`UNION` needs to be put between two simple queries, but yours is not.

You can do this:

```
(SELECT ...) UNION (SELECT ...);
```

But not:

```
(SELECT ...); UNION (SELECT ...);
```

By analogy, imagine if you were coding in Java or PHP or other language that terminates statement with a semicolon. The following attempt and adding two numbers would be an error:

```
i = 123;
  + 456;
```

Whereas this would be fine:

```
i = 123 + 456;
```